# Eclipse GIT, large Magento PHP project clone import

Tags: php, eclipse, git, magento

I have been trying to import a Magento PHP project from a local LAN FTP server to my PC Eclipse. The process takes a long time and fails, as the project is large (5GB+). I want to know if it is possible to bypass the import procedure of Eclipse and instead take the project compressed tarball to my PC and then use it as GIT team project, or any other solution. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

You can download your project files from admin side using `Backups` in magento, Its faster than your FTP download.

```
1. Goto`System->Tools->Backups`.
2. Create `System Backup` and `Database Backup`
3. Download the backups to your local machine.
```